# Issue in sp_send_dbmail with File Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `SP_Send_DBemail` to send an email with `@file_attachments` Parameter.

I am getting an error of invalid file path on below mentioned line.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_attachments", "~/Report/single_PO_print.pdf");
```

Comment: Well, did you make sure the path is correct? Have you done some debugging? What have you done so far? Kindly show us your effort.

Comment: post your code so that we can better understand what and how you are doing

Comment: `~` is a relative path for the web app. Use `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: As Daniel noted, it is better to give an absolute path for server where the SQL Server instance is running on